# Line in LineSeries disappearing when Scrollbar is used

Tags: amcharts

The problem appearing when the chart have Scrollbar and we try to use it. Line just disappearing from chart. Using **AmChart 4**

Here is codepen with example: https://codepen.io/smertelny/pen/jdyGZR

Already tried to change values from decimal to integers (just removed comma). No effect.

```
let data = [
    {
        "value": 27.75,
        "date": new Date(2019, 0, 31)
    },
    {
        "value": 27.77,
        "date": new Date(2019, 0, 30)
    },
    {
        "value":  27.79,
        "date": new Date(2019, 0, 29)
    },
    {
        "value": 27.81,
        "date": new Date(2019, 0, 28)
    },
    {
        "value": 27.78,
        "date": new Date(2019, 0, 27)
    }
]

let chart = am4core.create("chart", am4charts.XYChart);
let xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
let yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis())

xAxis.dataFields.category = "date";
xAxis.title.text = "Date";

let series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries())
let bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet())
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.tooltipText = "{valueY}"
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
series.name = "Value";
series.strokeWidth = 2;
chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();

chart.data = data;
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your dates need to be in ascending order for it to work with a DateAxis. Your dates are descending, which can lead into issues like the scrollbar breaking. Just call `reverse()` on your array:

```js
let data = [
    {
        "value": 27.75,
        "date": new Date(2019, 0, 31)
    },
    {
        "value": 27.77,
        "date": new Date(2019, 0, 30)
    },
    {
        "value":  27.79,
        "date": new Date(2019, 0, 29)
    },
    {
        "value": 27.81,
        "date": new Date(2019, 0, 28)
    },
    {
        "value": 27.78,
        "date": new Date(2019, 0, 27)
    }
].reverse();

let chart = am4core.create("chart", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.data = data;
let xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
let yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis())

xAxis.dataFields.category = "date";
xAxis.title.text = "Date";

let series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries())
let bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet())
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.tooltipText = "{valueY}"
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
series.name = "Value";
series.strokeWidth = 2;
chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed. Couldn't find nothing about that in documentation. You saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: I'd been stumped by this for a while too. Thanks! For reference, the Amcharts docs do have a section about ordering data (although you have to dig a little): https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Order_of_data_items

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CategoryAxis and remove let and replace its with the var :

```
var chart = am4core.create("chart", am4charts.XYChart);      
chart.paddingRight = 20;
chart.data = data;
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "date";
```

And also try to write date in commas. Like This:

```
var data = [
    {"value": 27.77,
     "date": "2018-12-12"
    }]
```

Comment: With CategoryAxis it is not disappearing, but there is a problem - chart is not just right, it shows 27.79 below 27.78 as it treats it as category, not a number. Date change did nothing =( (changed let to var, just in case, too)